# How to reset zoom.transform after zooming without reseting selections in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So I am using the `d3.zoom` and defining the `on` method and applying the transform manually to different elements. But when another panning/zooming occurs, it gives the transformation from the original state to current state. I want it to give me only from the last state to current state.

For example: first I zoom into the view which gives me a transformation something like this: `{x=0,y=0,k=2}`. Next time, if I pan the view to right, the `transform` object in the `event` is `{x=2,y=0,k=2}`. But I want it to give me `{x=2,y=0,k=1}`. So I need to somehow reset the zoom to `d3.zoomIdentity` without changing the element transformation. How do I do this?

Below is a code snippet explaining what I want:

```js
d3.zoom().on("zoom", event => {
  console.log(event.transform); // {x=1, y=5, k=0.5}
  recalculateVertices(event.transform);
  recalculateEdges(event.transform);

  // Now I want to reset the transform of zoom to {x=0,y=0,k=1}
  // Something like this
  resetZoom(zoom);
  
  // So the next time again a zoom event occurs, it will give the 
  // event.transform as the transformation only from current state to that next state.
  // Instead of "from original state to current state". 
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call `selection.call(zoom.transform, zoomIdentity)` at the end of the on zoom callback. To avoid infinite recursion, you can skip the callback if the zoom transform is the identity:

```js
d3.zoom().on("zoom", event => {
  // Do nothing if the transform is the zoom identity. This avoids 
  //    infinite recursion with the last line of this callback
  if(event.transform.toString() === zoomIdentity.toString()) {
       return
  }
  console.log(event.transform); // {x=1, y=5, k=0.5}
  recalculateVertices(event.transform);
  recalculateEdges(event.transform);

  // "selection" is the d3 selection that calls zoom
  // "zoom" is the zoom behavior that gets called in the selection
  // "zoomIdentity" is the identity transform {x: 0, y: 0, k: 1}
  //    that is imported from d3
  selection.call(zoom.transform, zoomIdentity)
  // To avoid recursion (because the method above will trigger this callback
  //    again), the callback starts with a condition to do nothing when the zoom is 
  //    the identity transform
})
```

You might need to reorder the code a bit to reference the zoom and the selection on the callback:

```js
    const zoom = d3.zoom();
    const selection = ...;
    zoom.on('zoom', ...);
    selection.call(zoom);
```